# 2 Floating divs, Need the first one to auto-size according to parent div and 2nd floating div

Tags: css, layout, html, css-float

This is how my code may go:-

```
<div id="parent" style="width:49%">
  <div id="left" style="float:left;clear:both;width:auto">BLAH!BLAH!Content goes here</div>
  <div id="right" style="float:left;clear:both:width:250px">Content again goes here!</div>
</div>
```

So basically I want left to auto-size based on the the width of "right" but must stay in limits of the "parent" container!

I looked up many places but didn't find sensible answers! Hope this website can help me! :D

Thanks in advance

Comment: Pure CSS please because this code needs to work on Emails too! :D
Thanks once again everyone

Comment: Why is div#right floated left?

Comment: If you need it for emails, use tables. Email clients do not work well with CSS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Float `#right` to the right, and do not float `#left` but give it a `margin-right` which is equal to the width of `#right`. If you float `#left`, it will take up the size of its contents, but if you don't float it, it will take up the possible maximum width it can. And you just lower this maximum width by setting a margin.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bazmegakapa/sCzgf/2/)

Notice that in the markup I changed the order of divs:

```
  <div id="right">Content again goes here!</div>
  <div id="left">BLAH!BLAH!Content goes here</div>
```

And the important part of the CSS:

```
#parent { 
    width: /*whatever you need*/; 
    overflow: hidden; /* to let it take up the height of floated elements */
}

#left {
    margin-right: 250px;
}

#right {
    float: right;
    width: 250px;
}
```

Tested in FF4, Chrome, IE8.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use JavaScript to detect remaining space. This cannot be done with CSS alone. With jQuery you can do

```
var parentw = $('#parent').width();
var rightw = $('#right').width();
$('#left').width(parentw - rightw);
```

### Check working example http://jsfiddle.net/NP4vb/

Comment: You code works great but I want it to be in pure CSS, and I'm pretty sure it is possible! Once again, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Pure CSS Answer:

```
<div id="parent" style="width:49%">
  <div id="left" style="float:left;clear:both;width:calc(100% - 250px)">BLAH!BLAH!Content goes here</div>
  <div id="right" style="float:left;clear:both:width:250px">Content again goes here!</div>
</div>
```