# How to use the width that is left

Tags: html, css

I am having a left div width a fixed width of 200 px, then I want the content area to take the space that is left. How can I solve that? I have done this...but it doesn't work.

```
   #sidebar {
        float:left;
        width:200px;
        height:100%;
        background-color: blue;
    }

#mainContent {
    float:left;
    width: // USE WHATEVER SPACE IS LEFT;
    height:100%;
    background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [2 Floating divs, Need the first one to auto-size according to parent div and 2nd floating div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5645746/2-floating-divs-need-the-first-one-to-auto-size-according-to-parent-div-and-2nd)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at this code:

http://jsfiddle.net/Ffx8R/

CSS:

```
#sidebar {
    float:left;
    width:200px;
    height:100%;    
}

#mainContent {

    padding-left:200px;
    height:100%;

    border:1px blue solid;
}
#container
{


    height:200px;
    clear:both;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="sidebar">here is sidebar info</div>
    <div id="mainContent">main Content info</div>
</div>
```